# Apache HTTP Server - How to print to console on modules?

Tags: c++, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I have an Apache HTTP Server module called mod_mymodule.so following the documentation [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html).

I would really like to see my own `std::cout`'s, so I could see in run-time my module being loaded and what is happening inside, such as:

```
static int myserver_handler(request_rec *r)
{
    std::cout << "WHY CAN'T I SEE THIS ON THE TERMINAL????" << std::endl; // <----????
    return OK;
}

static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *pool)
{
    ap_hook_handler(myserver_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_LAST);
}

module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA   tofserver_module =
{
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
    NULL,            // Per-directory configuration handler
    NULL,            // Merge handler for per-directory configurations
    NULL,            // Per-server configuration handler
    NULL,            // Merge handler for per-server configurations
    NULL,            // Any directives we may have for httpd
    register_hooks   // Our hook registering function
};
```

Comment: C is not C++ is not C is not C++ is not C.

Comment: You may need to open your own log file to see anything. Your module exists inside another program, so you have to play by their rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running Apache in debug mode will output to the terminal:

```
sudo apache2ctl -X
```